# Interesting infinite sum. Arcatan and parameter.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have no idea where to start with the following problem. I know this result, though, maybe helps(?): $\arctan(a)-\arctan(b)=\arctan{\dfrac{a-b}{1+ab}}$. Find the convergence of this one:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^a-(\arctan n)^a\right), a\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: There's a relation between $\arctan (n)$ and $\arctan (1/n)$ that you could exploit.

Comment: Their sum is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ when $n>0$. I will try. Thanks!

Comment: With Daniel's hint, we can rewrite the sum as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \arctan(1/n) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac {\pi}{2}\right)^{a(n-k)}(\arctan n)^{ak}
$$
but I don't know how helpful this really is

Comment: Arcatan sounds like a complicated way of saying identity function

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:** Compute the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\pi/2)^a - \arctan(n)^a}{n^{-1}}
$$
(for example, using L'Hôpital's rule). Note that the limit neither zero nor infinite, and apply the limit comparison test to conclude that your sum diverges for all $a \neq 0$.

---

**Computation:** Note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\pi/2)^a - (\arctan n)^a}{n^{-1}} = 
\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{(\pi/2)^a - \arctan^a(1/t)}{t} = \\
-\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{d}{dt} [\arctan^a(1/t)]|_{t=0} = 
\lim_{t \to 0^+} a \arctan^{a-1}(1/t) \cdot \frac{1}{1 + t^{-2}} \cdot t^{-2} =\\
\lim_{t \to 0^+} a \arctan^{a-1}(1/t) \cdot \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} =
a\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{a-1}
$$
And this will be non-zero as long as $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, something can be done using the hint from the comments. In particular, we can use $\arctan(1/n) \sim 1/n$ and $\arctan(n) \sim \pi/2$ to rewrite the summation as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n}\left[\left(\pi/2\right)^{a}\right]^n
$$
now, note that $(\pi/2)^a > 1$ lies outside the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum \frac 1n x^n$ whenever $a>0$.  Mysteriously, this leads to the wrong conclusion for $a<0$